# Driver for Sound Blaster X-Fi HD

Tags: drivers, sound, soundcard, sound-blaster

Do anyone know if there is drivers for Sound Blaster X-Fi HD ?

And if not, is there any other good external soundcard that includes headphone amps?

I bought some Sennheiser 595 HD Headphones, and need a card that can drive them.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you referring to? In 10.10, there is a driver snd-ctxfi included with the kernel. I have an internal X-Fi but it worked out of the box for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Sound Blaster X-Fi HD USB works out of the box with Ubuntu 11.04.